# Capistrano 3 copy strategy equivalent

Tags: ruby, git, capistrano

I updated to Cap 3 and it appears that `set :deploy_via, :copy` is no longer supported. In the [release annoucement](http://www.capistranorb.com/2013/06/01/release-announcement.html) there is a link to a video for replicating the copy strategy which currently returns a 404.

I used the `:copy` strategy because the server did not have access to `git` or access to the repository because it was behind a firewall.

What is the best way to replicate this functionality with v3?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and posted a similar question on the capistrano google group.

See here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/capistrano/BRa4Vj1_mEo

Short answer: Write your own rake task.

The capistrano maintainer provided some example code, via a blog post on his website, that can be found here: http://lee.hambley.name/2013/06/11/using-capistrano-v3-with-chef.html

In the end, we've decided to go w/ a different strategy entirely, and implement a mirror repository on the same network as our servers.

Answer (score 2):

There is one work in the exact same way

https://github.com/xuwupeng2000/capsitrano-scm-gitcopy

Capistrano 3 :copy

A copy strategy for Capistrano 3, which mimics the `:copy` scm of Capistrano 2.
This Gem is inspired by and based on https://github.com/wercker/capistrano-scm-copy.
Thank wercker so much.

This will make Capistrano **tar the a specific git branch, upload it to the server(s) and then extract it in the release directory**.

## Usage

`cap uat deploy -s branch=(your release branch)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use its gem - https://github.com/WildZero/capistrano-scm-tar-copy

set:

`set :scm, :copy`

`set :include_dir, '/User/w1ldzer0/ExampleDir'`

and go