# How to deploy with Capistrano 3 to a server, which can't access the scm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I would like to deploy a rails application with Capistrano 3. This rails application is under version control (git), but the server I want to deploy to can't access this git repository, because it's only accessible from the local network.

I've used Capistrano 2 a few times in this scenario by using `set :deploy_via, :copy`, but the support for this has been dropped in Capistrano 3 as it seems.

Can I use Capistrano 3 in this scenario? If no, what would you suggest?

Comment: Assuming you've seen this question already: [Capistrano 3 copy strategy equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508411/capistrano-3-copy-strategy-equivalent)?

Comment: Yep, I came across this. Why they dropped deployment via copy?

Comment: If [this](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/695#issuecomment-26487649) is to be believed, the owner owner wasn't using it and it was a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the option `set :deploy_via, :copy` was only available until the version 3 of Capistrano, I need to find another solution.

I ended up with another git repository on the deployment machine. So I've just added another remote to the git repository and pushing all changes to the deployment repository, before I run Capistrano.

According to that, my repository url is set to the local repository on the deployment machine:

```
set :repo_url, 'file:///opt/git/example.com.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is a reimplementation of :copy scm. It is a gem you can find it here:**

https://github.com/xuwupeng2000/capsitrano-scm-gitcopy